# "FormatException" not thrown when ToInt32() method has invalid argument type

Tags: c#, .net, console

1)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        a = Convert.ToInt32( "a" );
        Console.Write(a);
    }
}
```

I get `FormatException` with message: `Input string was not in a correct format`. and this is quite understood.

2)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        a = Convert.ToInt32( Console.Read() );
        Console.Write(a);
    }
}
```

In second case, I can type any characters, for example `abc` and it displayed in console.

Question: Why doesn't throw `FormatException` in second case and why it works successfully with non `int` characters?

**UPDATE**

with `Console.ReadLine()` method, which returns `string` type, also not trown `FormatException` and printed any character in console successfully.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: simple anwser just by looking at the first line of the documentation or event by mouse over .Read() in visual studio

Comment: Yes,  `Console.Read()`  returns `int` type, but this code also not throws exception and works, if use `console.ReadLine()` method, which returns `string` type

Comment: _"this code also not throws exception and works, if use console.ReadLine() method, which returns string type"_ - nope, that's not true. Show the code and your input for that latter claim.

Comment: @ CodeCaster - please see update in question

Comment: You do not show the input. The code under "update" will work if you input numbers.

Comment: @ CodeCaster how can I show you the input? when I type "asd" on keyboard, in console displayed `asd` without any exception. or  you say me something else?

Comment: Yes, by "input" I mean what you type. `Console.ReadLine()` waits for an Enter keypress... It prints the characters you type, but only returns the input after you press Enter. Then you'll get your exception.

Comment: @CodeCaster - O, Your last comment is "The Moment of Truth", :) thank you, this is answer on my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [return type of `Console.Read()` is an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx).

You then call [`Convert.ToInt32(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a76a1x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns the specified 32-bit signed integer; no actual conversion is performed.

Comment: someone down-vote your question and mine without leaving comment!

Answer (score 5):

Because the output of the [`Console.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is **int**. It means it get the **int** representation of what you have typed, so if you type character it actually get the int representation of that character, and everything is ok.

To see what is happening in detail:

```
int a;
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());  //input for example: abc
Console.WriteLine(a);                 //97
Console.WriteLine((char)a);           //a
```

Comment: Downvoter, consider leaving a comment and say your reason

Answer (score 4):

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The next character from the input
>   stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters
>   to be read.

```
public static int Read()
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

**FormatException** : Value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Answer (score 3):

I *strongly* suspect you are mixing with `Console.ReadLine` and `Console.Read` methods.

From [`Console.Read` doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream.

and

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 **The next character** from the input
>   stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters
>   to be read.

That means when you put `abc` with this method it returns `97` ([because `97` is the ascii value of the first character](http://www.asciitable.com/)) which is a valid integer.

Answer (score 3):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

ToInt32 does have an overloaded version that can take a string, but the string must be a representation of a real number; "a" is not a number, but if you had "101" it would parse correctly-

```
int a;
a = Convert.ToInt32("101");  //will parse to int
Console.Write(a);

a = Convert.ToInt32("a");  //will not parse to int
Console.Write(a);
```

The reason your second example works while the first one doesn't, is because Console.Read returns the **integer** value based on the next character passed into it, so all is fine when you call ToInt32 with it.

UPDATE-

Just tested it with ReadLine too, and it still gave me an error.

[image]